# Ordering a DataRowCollection

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

How can we sort a `DataRowCollection` in ASP.NET WebForms similar `List` in ASP.NET MVC?

```
public DataRowCollection GetSortedRow(DataRowCollection dataRows)
    {
      var sortedResult =  dataRows.OrderBy(d => d["Name"])

    }
```

The OrderBy method does not exist for DataRowCollection.

Comment: You should order the source data, not the DataRowCollection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert the datatable to enumerable as follows:

```
public EnumerableRowCollection<DataRow> GetSortedRows(DataTable table)
{
  var rows = table.AsEnumerable();
  return rows.OrderByDescending(r => r["Name"]);           
}
```